# Why ApplicationUser instead of User in ASP.Net Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, naming-conventions, naming

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC and Identity. I couldn't find any reason why they named the derived class `ApplicationUser` instead of simply `User`. Is there any difference or reason?

Comment: This is like *I need to find something to ask*

Comment: @Simonare Why is that? Naming matters to me. This is like *I need to ask*.

Comment: I hope that you can get proper explaination.